# How to manipulate long one-string text file from front to end and store variables in a list in R?

Tags: r, string, text

I have one text file which has around 1,000 sets of `NAME` and `N` as shown below (I picked only two sets for simplicity).

```
    NAME="2 B11101001",
     N=5049, 20016, 5163, 20081, 5161, 20431, 5023, 5219, 5221,
       5225, 5223, 5227, 5003, 5105, 20623, 5107, 5109, 5111, 5113, 5121, 5007
    NAME="1 A2110111 >",
     N=12034, 2195, 2197, 2199, 2201, 2109, 2032, 20295, 2203, 2205,
       2207, 2107, 2177, 20546, 11528, 20196, 2105, 21031, 11526,
       11011, 11013, 11512, 11225, 11227, 11229, 13169, 13171,
       13173, 11231, 21128, 11233, 10502, 10500, 10498, 10496,
       10494, 11912, 11778, 10492, 11946, 10490, 10488, 11802,
       10486, 11834, 10484, 11844, 10482, 10478, 11694, 11037,
       12087, 12965, 12957, 12953, 12089, 12091, 12481, 12549,
       12941, 12483, 12101, 12103, 12933, 11800, 12927, 11810,
       12923, 12105, 12111, 12113, 12731, 12739, 20806, 12745,
       12117, 12119, 12503, 10264, 11079, 10262, 12505, 12499,
       14431, 14423, 11649, 11677, 14421, 11081, 14461
```

I need to load this text file and convert it into `list` format which looks like this:

```
$ NAME
[1] 2 B11101001
[2] 1 A2110111 >
$ N
[1] 5049 20016 5163 20081 ... 
[2] 12034 2195 2197 ...
```

`NAME` is an identifier of a set of `N`.
`N` indicates sequential order of nodes.

I have another sets of `NAME` and other attributes in `data.frame` format looks like this:

```
NAME          FARE     FREQUENCY
2 B11101001   1000     10
1 A2110111 >  2000     5
```

These will be merged with the loaded text file like this:

```
$ NAME
[1] 2 B11101001
[2] 1 A2110111 >
$ N
[1] 5049 20016 5163 20081 ... 
[2] 12034 2195 2197 ...
$FARE
[1] 1000
[2] 2000
$FREQUENCY
[1] 10
[2] 5
```

I think I can merge these two data sets, however I do not have any idea how to load a text file which does not follow ordinal comma-separated format.

Currently I loaded the text file using `readChar` function but cannot find the ways to convert it into list.

[image]

As explained,`NAME` is an identifier to determine the beginning of a set of `N`. `N` is a simple set of numbers delimited by a comma (but its order shall be kept). The next pair starts when we find next `NAME`. Any ways to implement this?

Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the `ReadLines()` function to input the text into R.
Then identify the rows beginning with "NAME=" and "N=" separate the lines into different groups remove the unwanted parts from each line and combine into the appropriate vectors.
See the comments in the script for more information.

```
#read text into R
text <-readLines("Stackquestion.txt")

#find rows with Name and clean up
namerows <- grep("NAME=", text)
namelist <- gsub('",', "", trimws(gsub('NAME="', "", text[namerows])))


#find rows with N
Nrows <- grep("N=", text)

ranges <- c((namerows[-1]-1), length(text))

#Remove the line breaks on the N= rows and combine
Nlist <-sapply(1:length(Nrows), function(i){
   cleantext<-trimws(text[Nrows[i]:ranges[i]])
   cleantext <- gsub('N=', "", cleantext)
   cleaned<-paste(cleantext, collapse = "")
   cleaned
})


> namelist
[1] "2 B11101001"  "1 A2110111 >"
> Nlist
[1] "5049, 20016, 5163, 20081, 5161, 20431, 5023, 5219, 5221,5225, 5223, 5227, 5003, 5105, 20623, 5107, 5109, 5111, 5113, 5121, 5007"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[2] "12034, 2195, 2197, 2199, 2201, 2109, 2032, 20295, 2203, 2205,2207, 2107, 2177, 20546, 11528, 20196, 2105, 21031, 11526,11011, 11013, 11512, 11225, 11227, 11229, 13169, 13171,13173, 11231, 21128, 11233, 10502, 10500, 10498, 10496,10494, 11912, 11778, 10492, 11946, 10490, 10488, 11802,10486, 11834, 10484, 11844, 10482, 10478, 11694, 11037,12087, 12965, 12957, 12953, 12089, 12091, 12481, 12549,12941, 12483, 12101, 12103, 12933, 11800, 12927, 11810,12923, 12105, 12111, 12113, 12731, 12739, 20806, 12745,12117, 12119, 12503, 10264, 11079, 10262, 12505, 12499,14431, 14423, 11649, 11677, 14421, 11081, 14461"
```